# Are there true references of Clara in the classic episodes?

Tags: doctor-who

Please keep in mind I have only seen few of the classic episodes, so this may be very obvious for anyone that did see them.

*The Name of the Doctor spoilers:*

> Supposedly, copies of Clara end up in many moments of the Doctor's life. The two obvious ones are Dalek Asylum and victorian London.
>  
>  When Clara enters the Doctor's time stream, multiple classic scenes are shown (with Clara inserted). Since I have not seen the referenced episodes, I can't tell whether there is a real reference to *something* that happened in those episodes.
>  
> For example, we see a scene where the Doctor is driving a yellow car (Bessie?), and passes by Clara. In the classic episode, does the Doctor *actually* pass by *someone* that turns around while driving Bessie in *that* scene?
>  
> I realize of course that if there was anyone there, she was not meant to be Clara (in the classic series), but it would be nice to know whether Moffat did an effort to reference the classic episodes more deeply. Because that would be pretty cool...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, sort of. The clip of Sylvester McCoy (the Seventh Doctor) was from the end of episode 1 of Dragonfire, which is widely acknowledged as the stupidest cliffhanger in the show's history: walking along a cliff path, he decides - for no apparent reason - to climb down and hang from his umbrella on the cliff, almost falls, then in the next episode climbs up without difficulty.

So the use of that clip is presumably intended to imply that the Doctor didn't just climb down for no reason: something (i.e. the Great Intelligence) made him do it, and something else (i.e. Clara) was responsible for rescuing him.

Comment: I'm not enough of a Classic Who expert to add much, but io9 pointed out [this scene](http://observationdeck.io9.com/there-could-be-something-amazing-hidden-in-next-weeks-503083269) from *The Five Doctors*, and they included the original unedited scene for comparison.

Comment: Well, I'm glad they did reference something. Would've loved a bit more though - wasted potential there D:... heck, they could've used her to cover up any plot holes they had! XD

Comment: Question: I was reading in http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Susan_Foreman and found *"The First Doctor and Susan planned to leave Gallifrey together by purloining a faulty TARDIS from the repair shop beneath the Capitol. They were about to leave in one model, but a young woman accosted the Doctor and advised him to steal a different one which was "more fun." "* - was this added after this episode, or did it actually happen?

Comment: That was added afterwards. We've never seen the actual moment they stole the Tardis before. I believe that clip was originally from a completely different occasion, although I'm not sure when.